# required output for below recursive function code

Tags: python

Am learning Python and gone through this recursive function, i walked through program and not able to figure the output

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if k > 0:
        result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

Output

```
Recursion Example Results
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

Can anyone walk through this program and explain me the output?

Comment: With pycharm you can set a breakpoint and walk through your program inspecting values at any step. It seems like a good time to learn how to use a debugger. Can be very helpful for the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

You called `tri_recursion(6)`
And, at the 3rd line, tri_recursion function before exiting from function.
I wrote each step as below:

```
tri_recursion(6) = 6 + tri_recursion(5)                          // 21 is printed
                 = 6 + (5 + tri_recursion(4))                    // 15 is printed
                 = 6 + (5 + (4 + tri_recursion(3))               // 10 is printed
                 = 6 + (5 + (4 + (3 + tri_recursion(2)))         // 6 is printed
                 = 6 + (5 + (4 + (3 + (2 + tri_recursion(1))))   // 3 is printed
                 = 6 + (5 + (4 + (3 + (2 + (1 + tri_recursion(0)))))  // 1 is printed
```